# mark match and connmark match in single iptable rule

Tags: iptables

I want to add connmark match with mark match in single iptable rule. I can add these rules individually,

```
iptables -t mangle -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -i eth2 -m connmark --mark 0x1/0xf
iptables -t mangle -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -i eth2 -m mark --mark 0x1/0xf
```

But while adding below rule, it throws error.

```
iptables -t mangle -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -i eth2 -m mark --mark 0x1/0xf -m connmark --mark 0x1/0xf

Error: iptables v1.4.7: mark: "--mark" option may only be specified once
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Is this supported in iptables? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for trouble. I've found solution for this case. It has been fixed in 1.4.8.

http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/changes-iptables-1.4.8.txt